Unable to run make protoc grpc_php_plugin when create clients in PHP for gRPC services
I'm trying to generating a zeebe-php client stub while referring to this documentation.
I manage to run these command succeffuly:-
$ cd grpc $ mkdir -p cmake/build $ pushd cmake/build $ cmake ../..
But when run make protoc grpc_php_plugin, the response give is "make: *** No rule to make target 'protoc'.  Stop."
I check all the requirements and all passed and did install protoc.
I expect it to be able to run and compile the proto files

What happens if you just run make with no arguments?  Maybe the cmake files don't define targets with exactly those names.  Do you see a Makefile file in your directory?  Maybe cmake chose a different generator, not the Makefile generator...

when I run make in (C:\grpc\cmake\build), the response is make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
I can see the Makefile file is on the root folder, (C:\grpc)

Then you must have run cmake from the wrong directory.  CMake creates a makefile in the CURRENT directory, where you invoked the cmake command, and that's the same directory you should run make in.  If there's no makefile there, then something is definitely wrong.
